# How can I get the value from div with a given class in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```html
<div class="date-time-container">
  <!----> 
  <!----> 
  <div class="event-start-date event-period-info">
    <!----> 
    <div class="start-time">21:45</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Given the code above, how can I get the value "21:45" from the code using Selenium Webdriver?

I tried the following, but the value is empty in both cases:

```
var match = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div[class='date-time-container']"));
```

and

```
string start24 = match.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[class='start-time']")).Text.ToString();
```

Also with xpath and getAttribute the value is empty.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry. It's my first time posting. I've corrected the post now.